# What can we say about the stability of this equilibrium with purely imaginary eigenvalues?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, nonlinear-dynamics

**Equations**

I have the following system of Lotka-Volterra equations:

$x'(t)=ax(t)-bx(t)y(t)$

$y'(t)=-gy(t) + dx(t)y(t)$.

This system has a non-trivial equilibrium of:

$(x^*,y^*)=(\frac{g}{d},\frac{a}{b})$.

The eigenvalues corresponding to this equilibrium are both purely imaginary:

$-i\sqrt{ag}$ and $i\sqrt{ag}$.

**Question**
Can we conclude anything about the stability of the equilibrium (global or otherwise) despite the eigenvalues being purely imaginary?

I have been reading about the dynamics of this classic system (e.g., on Wikipedia), but have not found any information regarding the stability of the oscillatory equilibrium.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Firstly, linearize the system around the equilibrium point and examine the linearized model's eigenvalues. If the real part of the eigenvalues is zero, then the method is inconclusive.

Comment: ^ cont., if the first method fails, you need further analysis. There is a possibility that the second Lyapunov method will work.